# d3.create() returns an element with .node(), but does not display in the browser

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

1. I am trying to get D3.js to generate rectangle elements with **d3.create()**. It does not work/display.
2. First, I create a *rectangle()* function, which returns an element:

   ```js
   function rectangle() {

       _el = d3.create("rect")
           .attr("stroke", "black")
           .attr("fill", "black")
           .attr("stroke-width", "10px")
           .attr("x", 0)
           .attr("y", 0)
           .attr("width", 300)
           .attr("height", 200);

       return _el

   }
   ```
3. I then create an SVG selection, to which I append an instance of *rectangle().node()*:

   ```js
   const SVG_WIDTH = 1000;
   const SVG_HEIGHT = 1000;

   svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
       .attr("width", SVG_WIDTH)
       .attr("height", SVG_HEIGHT)
       .attr("id", "generated")

   svg.append(
       // () => rectangle().node()
       function () { return rectangle().node() }
   )
   ```
4. Yet there is no visual output in my browser (Google Chrome).
5. However, when I look into the DOM (via Chrome's 'Elements' tab), D3 has generated the correct SVG/rectangle code:

   ```html
   <svg width="1000" height="1000" id="generated">
       <rect stroke="black" fill="black" stroke-width="10px" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="200" rx="10" ry="10"></rect>
   </svg>
   ```
6. In fact, If I copy the above code and place it anywhere else in my HTML file without modification, a rectangle appears in my browser.
7. Why is SVG's modification of the browser DOM not showing/working, yet the code it generates is correct and will show up when manually copy/pasted into the HTML?

Comment: Is it initiated with the onload event?

Comment: No, it was not. The <body> tag had no attributes.

Answer (score 7):

From [d3.create documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#create):

> This method assumes the HTML namespace, so you must specify a namespace explicitly when creating SVG or other non-HTML elements [...]

```js
    d3.create("svg") // equivalent to svg:svg  
    d3.create("svg:svg") // more explicitly  
    d3.create("svg:g") // an SVG G element  
    d3.create("g") // an HTML G (unknown) element
```

Thus, the function that creates the rectangle should use `svg:rect`. Otherwise it will create an "HTML rect" instead of an "SVG rect".

The `d3.create` method by default creates elements in the HTML namespace. When you use `d3.create('rect')` you're not creating an SVG rectangle, but instead an HTML rectangle (which don't exist in the HTML specification). The element appears at the DOM, but the browser don't know how to render it (it has the name of an SVG element, but is not an SVG element), so it does not appear on the screen.

Every HTML element has an implict `xhtml:` prefix, and every SVG element inside an SVG implicitly has an `svg:` prefix. Usually you don't need to worry about it because the namespace is often obvious enough to be handled by the library. However, `d3.create` can't tell which one you want, because it is a detached element; so it defaults to HTML.

So, even though both `svg:rect` and `xhtml:rect` have the same name on the DOM, they refer to different specifications, and the only one that makes sense for browsers is the `svg:rect`.

Comment: I've just tried this - _d3.create(svg:rect)_ works! Thank you very much! Please correct my understanding, if I am mistaken - d3.create() always/by default creates an element in the window namespace/object? But in my earlier case, I did not specify 'svg:rect', so why does the rectangle still appear in the DOM's <svg> tag (even though it does not appear in the browser)?

Comment: @xax I edited the answer to elaborate on the differences between an HTML rect and an SVG rect.

Comment: I appreciate the more thorough answer, and fully understand the difference now. Thank you.